# Input text's ajax call inside p:dataTable taking long to render response

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a complex page in my application. I am using JSF 2.0 PrimeFaces 5.0.
From the backend I am getting the response for the corresponding call within a 1-3 sec but to render response in the xhtml it is taking 13-15sec. Total time to get response in the page is around 15-18sec for a single row of the table. at max it will be 300 rows I am worrying about the performance. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue. I mentioned my sample bean code and xhtml ajax call component. Please refer.

My managed bean is in `@ConversationScoped`

Sample xhtml:

```
<p:tabView dynamic="true" cache="true" >

 <p:outputPanel id="summaryPanel" >
 .....
 </p:outputPanel>

<p:tab>

<p:dataTable id="dtGpcReqDetailsOri" value=#{bean.list} var="object" >
<p:column>
    <h:inputText id="amount" style="width: 45px !important; text-align: right !important;" styleClass="dt-input-small add-left-margin-sm"
    validator="#{bean.validateAmount}"
    onkeypress="if(event.which &lt; 48 || event.which &gt; 57) return false;"
    maxlength="6" value="#{tableObject.amount}">
    <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" listener="#{bean.processOnAmount(object)}"
    update="dtGpcReqDetailsOri,:tabView:summaryPanel}" />
                                            </h:inputText>

                                                </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>                          
    </p:tab>                                            
</p:tabView>
```

// **this is taking only 1-3 sec to execute** 
Sample bean:

```
public void processOnAmount(Object object){
calculateTotalAndAveragesForAmount(object);
procedureCheckCall(object);
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Just now I tried to debug the life cycle faces with sysout.
Log:

```
[10/3/18 11:21:13:437 IST] 00000055 SystemOut     O Executed Phase RESTORE_VIEW(1)
[10/3/18 11:21:13:447 IST] 00000055 SystemOut     O Execution Time = 145ms
[10/3/18 11:21:13:447 IST] 00000055 SystemOut     O Executed RESTORE_VIEW Phase APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES(2)
[10/3/18 11:21:13:457 IST] 00000055 SystemOut     O Executed RESTORE_VIEW Phase PROCESS_VALIDATIONS(3)
[10/3/18 11:21:13:465 IST] 00000055 SystemOut     O Executed RESTORE_VIEW Phase UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES(4)
[10/3/18 11:21:13:518 IST] 00000055 SystemOut     O Executed RESTORE_VIEW Phase INVOKE_APPLICATION(5)
[10/3/18 11:21:14:360 IST] 00000055 SystemOut     O Executed RESTORE_VIEW Phase RENDER_RESPONSE(6)
[10/3/18 11:21:14:360 IST] 00000055 SystemOut     O Execution Time = 1058ms
```

the response is getting with in 1058ms but page loading until 15-17sec>

Is there any issue with the page components?

Comment: Both your JSF and PrimeFaces versions are old. Tried upgrading?

Comment: No it is a live application. So we can not upgrade as of now..

Comment: TRY, if it works in [mcve] flavour in 6.2, you can see what the bugfixes are and try to createca patch or decide to upgrade

Comment: Are you actually meaning that if use e.g. an h:textArea it is not slow? Or some other component? And did you try without the tab? And did you check if it is slow on the client? And it is related to the number of records returned (10.000 can be slow) and... Well I hope you get the picture... ;-)

Comment: I tried with other components with ajax call also still i m facing same issue. Even without tab also getting the same amount of response time. But the thing is incase of having large number (300+ records) of records it is taking much time to render.

Comment: Since the server is 'quick' the client is most likely the culprit (or a really bad network). Debug client-side with a profiler (and try different browsers and versions)

Comment: Any progress???

Comment: Yes today i got an alternative way to update the specific row of the table.

Comment: Yeah.. some of the components from my datatable is blocking the render response but not sure which component it is. Meanwhile got a temporary fix.. I have updated the particular column’s component id of the corresponding row alone instead of updating the whole table. It is working fine now but need to figure out the exact component Thanks for asking 